# 2 identical functions, but one hangs

Tags: bash

I can't wrap my brain around why one of these functions works just fine [status-up], but the other simply hangs with no output at all. [status-rec]

Both `pidfile` and `recfile` are valid paths to their respective PID files in `/var/run/`, and both contain only a PID number with no line breaks or other non-printable chars.

```
status-up() {
    if [ -f ${pidfile} ]; then
        if ps p $(cat ${pidfile}) >> /dev/null; then
            printf "Upload running as PID %s\n" $(cat ${pidfile})
            return
        fi
    fi
    echo "Upload is not running"
}

status-rec() {
    if [ -f ${recfile} ]; then
        if ps p $(cat ${recfile}) >> /dev/null; then
            printf "Receive running as PID %s\n" $(cat ${recfile})
            return
        fi
    fi
    echo "Receive is not running"
}
```

Comment: Does one work and the other hang when `$pidfile` and `$recfile` have the same value? Otherwise, that seems like quite a plausible reason why one works and one doesn't: they have different input. In that case try running `status-up` setting `$pidfile` to one path, then the other, and then the same with `status-rec`, and you'll see if it's really the functions at fault or the input.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky: I don't really understand your comment. The two functions are literally identical except for the file they use; I don't think there's any question but that they'd behave the same if they used the same file. The question is why one file causes its function to hang, while the other does not.

Comment: Andalso, notice `cat` hangs if no input is given -- as well as many other programs. One of your paths are most probably empty.

Comment: To add to Rubens' comment: note that if `[ ... ]` has only one argument, it checks that argument for non-nullity; so if `$recfile` is empty or unset, then `[ -f ${recfile} ]` is `[ -f ]` is `true` (since `-f` is a non-empty string). This is one reason that you should always wrap parameter expansions in double-quotes: `[ -f "$recfile" ]` would not have this misbehavior.

Comment: @ruakh My comment was challenging the OP's apparent assumption (based on the way the question was written) that the difference in behavior is due to something about the functions themselves, rather than the input.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky: I think you're making a distinction without a difference. The difference between the functions is the input they use, ergo, any difference in the inputs *is* a difference between "the functions themselves". (Note that the OP described the contents of the files. Also note that (s)he's not a blithering idiot.)

Comment: @ruakh In my last comment I used "the functions themselves" to refer to the code in the question, explicitly excluding the input. Pretend I used different wording for that if it helps. The overall point I was making is the same one you are.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky: We're certainly not making the same point. Your point is that the OP seems to have made a nonsensical assumption; my point is that (s)he obviously didn't make that assumption!

Comment: @ruakh Oh, OK. I meant that we are both making the point that the difference comes from the input, not from the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cat` hangs if no input is given -- as well as many other programs. One of your paths are most probably empty, as you're able to go through the `if` statement:

```
$ if [ -f ]; then echo "foo"; fi  
foo
```

Once you inside the block, you hang on the call `cat <empty>`. As pointed by @ruakh, you should get it to work double-quoting the variable.

Comment: Is it also possible that one of the files is in use?

Comment: This was it. Apparently when I wrote that function I was temporarily high or something. The variable is `${recpid}`, not `${recfile}`.

Comment: @Sammitch Haha! We all get high sometimes! I've just found out the last bug in an app I've been working on for close to one year was the simply caused by not flushing a file descriptor (: And it's  a distributed app, to make things a bit more entertaining! ^^